# Convert contents of div into an image to insert to pdf

Tags: javascript, image, html, pdf

Here's my situation. I have to make a report with graphs. I have already successfully created graphs (bar, pie, and line) using  [ChartJS](http://chartjs.devexpress.com/Demo)  and displayed them in my page. However, I want to put a "print" button which, when clicked, will generate a pdf containing all of the graphs created.

For my other pages (which are only forms), I have used TCPDF and it's working well. However, I can't use it again for the graphs because what I produced are widgets placed in div elements.

My plan is to convert the contents of these div elements (the graphs) into an image so I can insert it in TCPDF.

**Is there a way for me to convert the contents of the div into an image?**

I can't use canvas.toDataURL() like in this  [link](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/)  because ChartJS puts their graphs in a DIV element and NOT canvas. I also found out I can't put div inside a canvas ([see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763911/placing-a-div-within-a-canvas)).

Please help me (T^T)

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?