# Div inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i have a div element containing an interactive chart. Now i want to place it inside a canvas (using context or something) is it possible to do that? if yes, then what will be the solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placing a <div> within a <canvas>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763911/placing-a-div-within-a-canvas)

Comment: You can't place a div inside canvas. You may take a look at EasalJs http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS

Comment: A canvas element can only paint pixels, not html elements.  Is there a way for you to convert that chart into an image?  If so you can easily put the chart image on the canvas using context.drawImage.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a `div` inside a `canvas` and have it be displayed. It will only be displayed if the browser doesn't recognize the `canvas` element. There are ways, however, to position the `div` over the `canvas` so that the `canvas` acts as a sort of background to the content.

Comment: This is the way to achieve what you want.