# How can I draw a custom circle shape in CSS3?

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

I'm trying to draw this particular shape :

[image]

It has to have two straight faces, and I can't manage to create a better shape, other than a semicircle. Is it possible to somehow substract these portions from a circle with CSS, or should I just extract the image from the .psd file as it is ?

Comment: Surely this can be done. Just wait for a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken Tom answer and added overflow: hidden to the div.

This way, you don't need to set the div on the border of the body

CSS

```
#circle {
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#circle:after {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -5px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/gbY2C/23/)

Answer (score 3):

Do it with css after property like so:

```
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#circle:after {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
}
```

And in html:

```
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. The output is great but how do I do it if I want to place this image right in the middle of the html canvas ? I.E. I'm not allowed to use negative coordonates.

Comment: If you can't use negative coords, add `position: relative;` to `#circle` and replace top left in `circle:after` to `right: 15px; bottom: 15px`

Comment: If you use canvas, you should be able to draw this shape in it with javascript, or you could position div above it like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763911/placing-a-div-within-a-canvas)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="circle"> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbY2C/)

**Updated CSS**

```
  #circle {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 80px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 200px;
    }
```

Check this in Chrome, **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbY2C/18/)**

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but I think this is slightly different than the picture above. I want to create a circle with two straight edges and I've been surfing for results for more than a couple of hours. I'm pretty sure this can be done in css, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Yes, I need to replicate that image and I wanted to know if it can be done in CSS.