# Why the following JQuery UI code doesn't work to delete the dropped element?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I want some piece of code to delete the element dropped on the red div.I need the code to do the following:

1. Create the clicked element on "Canvas" div.
2. let the user drag the element
3. finally let the user delete the element by dropping it to red div.
   I hope I will get the best solution from here. here is the code:

   ```
   function makeResizable(x)
   {
     x = $(x);
     x.resizable();

   }
   function makeDraggable(x)
   {

     x = $(x);
         x.draggable();

    }

   function createPredefine(){
   $element = $(' <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="" height="45" width="110" 
   onDblClick="makeResizable(this)" />');
   $("#canvas").append($element);
   $element.draggable();
   }
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
   $( "#deleting_div" ).droppable({

       drop: function( event, ui ) {

           $(this).children().remove();
                       alert("trigger");

       }
     });
    });
   ```

   Create
       
       
       
       
                
               Components

   ```
           &nbsp &nbsp <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="" height="45" width="110" 
   onClick="createPredefine()"/> &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp <img 
   src="img/6.jpg" alt="" height="60" width="80" onClick="createCircle()"/>
           <br /><br >



           </div>
   </td>
   <td>
                 <div id="canvas" style="background- 
     color:#FFF;width:800px;height:700px;"> 
                 <div id="deleting_div" style="background- 
           color:red;widhth:50px;height:50px;"></div>  
                 <h2>&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp  &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 
            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 
                 &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 
             &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Draw Here</h2></div>
           </td>
           </tr>
            </table>
          </BODY>
           </HTML>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't place a  within a canvas (see [Placing a <div> within a <canvas>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763911/placing-a-div-within-a-canvas))

Canvas is like a painting, rather than a collection of Lego bricks - what you put on the canvas is flat and permanent.  The DOM is more like the collection of Lego bricks; you can pick one up and move it (and everything attached to it will move).

The closest you could get to moving something with a painting would probably just smudge the paint :)

What would probably be the most effective approach for what you are trying to do is create a "virtual" painting/canvas that is built of DOM objects and then "draw" that onto your canvas (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas)

Comment: This is a div having id="canvas" just for the sake of understanding. Drawing is working well, I am just asking about to remove the dropped object when drop event is fired from droppable div.

Comment: Oh, ARGH!  I didn't notice that!  I'm not very familiar with droppable, but doesn't the "drop" event have a reference to the dropped object?  If so, I would expect $(dropEvent.droppedObject).remove() to do the trick.

Comment: well, thanks ! I've changed the scenario and getting the work done by using some other logic and Click event.